# Saving file into Azure Blob

Tags: python-3.x, azure, python-requests, azure-functions

I am using below python code to save the file into local folder. I want to save this file into Azure Blob directly. I do not want file to be stored locally and then upload into blob.

I tried giving blob location in folder variable but it did not work. I have excel file that I want to read from Web browser and saved into Azure blobs using python.

```
 folder = 'Desktop/files/ab'
    
 r = requests.get(api_end_point, headers=api_headers, stream=True)
 with open(folder, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're reading a file from an api endpoint and then want to upload the contents of this file in blob storage without saving it first locally. Is that right?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Is your API endpoint publicly accessible? What I mean by that is if I take your API endpoint and paste it in browser, will I be able to see the contents of the file in the browser?

Comment: No, it is not. I am hitting Internal endpoint and able to download the file into local.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't be possible without downloading the content. You need not save it as a local file though. You can simply read the stream and create a blob using that stream.

Comment: thanks. I can pass string data to a container. How can I send bytes data to container?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code to store the string data as blob?

Comment: Would appreciate if you can put this code in question itself. It's not really readable in comments + things get lost in comments. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to pass the stream to your `upload_blob` method. Because you're passing stream, you don't need to use `blob_output = StringIO()
   blob_output.write(contents)`. Can you give that a try?

Comment: I tried and it did not work. what should I write at blob_output = StringIO() as in next line blob_output.write(contents) it says blob_output is not defined.

Comment: How Can I define blob_output for bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should get the files as something like stream.

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
```

---

```
connect_str = os.getenv('str')
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name = "test"
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, "MyFirstBlob.txt")
blob_client.upload_blob(req.get_body(), blob_type="BlockBlob")
```

On my side, I put the data in the body of request, and I upload that to azure blob. It is stream. You can also put a stream in it.

These are the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#upload-blobs-to-a-container

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=storage-py-v12

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=storage-py-v12#upload-blob-data--blob-type--blobtype-blockblob---blockblob----length-none--metadata-none----kwargs-

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me to define how you are putting data into the req object?

Comment: @Andrew On my side, I just use postman to post the data. You dont have to put a req body in the upload_blob() method, just any stream is ok.

Comment: @Andrew On my side, I use `req.get_body()`, but you dont need to do this. Just replace it with the stream you want to upload. On you side, you can read your excel file as stream and put the stream to the upload_blob() method.

Comment: @Andrew Can you mark my answer to end this question? Thanks.:)